# Securimage php library for Captcha Code showing security issues in Arachni Scanner

Tags: php, vulnerability-scanners, captcha

I have used the securimage PHP library to show a captcha on my form. But when I'm scanning my page for vulnerabilities using Arachni scanner, it shows the following message and it's trying to scan the same page with some different values repeatedly:

```
http://example.com/libs/classes/securimage/securimage_show.php
```

I have used the Captcha code in the form with the following method:

```
<?php require_once('libs/classes/securimage/securimage.php');
 echo(Securimage::getCaptchaHtml()); ?>
```

Arachni scanner is showing the following message:

> A modern web application will be reliant on several different 
>   programming languages.
>
> These languages can be broken up into two flavours.  These are
>   client-side languages (such as those that run in the  browser – like
>   JavaScript) and server-side languages (which are  executed by the
>   server – like ASP, PHP, JSP, etc.) to form the  dynamic pages
>   (client-side code) that are then sent to the client.
>
> Because all server-side code should be executed by the server,  it
>   should never be seen by the client. However, in some scenarios,  it is
>   possible that:
>
> The server-side code has syntax errors and therefore is not executed
>   by the server but is instead sent to the client. Using crafted
>   requests it is possible to force the server into  displaying the
>   source code of the application without executing it.
>
> As the server-side source code often contains sensitive information,
>   such as database connection strings or details into the application
>   workflow, this can be extremely risky.
>
> Cyber-criminals will attempt to discover pages that either 
>   accidentally or forcefully allow the server-side source code to be 
>   disclosed, to assist in discovering further vulnerabilities or 
>   sensitive information.
>
> Arachni has detected server-side source code within the server’s 
>   response.
>
> (False positives may occur when requesting binary files such as 
>   images (.JPG or .PNG) and may require manual verification.)

I have tried to pass the session_id() in parameter to validate the class method. I also used another parameter to stop directly showing the captcha image in the URL but with no luck.
What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: This might be a false positive. Note that Arachni is telling you that this may trigger a false positive when requesting binary files such as images, which is exactly what Securimage does. The response is an image that it retrieves for you.

Comment: yes, it may be possible in my case. the code generate images from random array and get some parameters which do not allow the scanner to terminate checking...

Answer (score 2):

> (False positives may occur when requesting binary files such as images (.JPG or .PNG) and may require manual verification.)

This is telling you pretty much everything you need to know. You're including a binary file, and the scanner knows that it has trouble distinguishing between server-side source code and binary files.

It's safe to assume that this is a **false positive**.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the provided code does have a syntax error:

> echo(Securimage::getCaptchaHtml();

You either add another `)` before the `;` or remove the first `(` since echo is not a function and using () with it is redundant.

If that doesn't fix the arachni error, what is the html output when you access that page directly?

Comment: Sorry, this is my mistake when copy and paste the code. there is  no syntax error, let me edit the code